# simple button and check button difference style

Tags: devexpress, simplebutton

There is a theme difference between the button in the training video and the button that appears on me, how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any user settings, it might look different depending on your version of Windows or theme.
If you want to make it the same as the training video, change the skin of Devexpress project setting.

The Devxpress project setting can be found in the Visual studio menu under Extensions - Devexpress - Winform controls .

If you change the skin, the appearance of all items in the form changes depending on the skin. If you want to change only the skin of the simplebutton, you need to create a user skin.